# Existing pattern/approach for a case where several objects of the same class each operate on their own chunk of a single shared contiguous array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

My situation is as follows, I am building a mesh (a series of points in 3D space with several values/properties specified at each point).The arrays of data that represent this mesh are passed into a solver which then does its thing.

The mesh is representing a group of objects, so the data on the mesh is specified object-wise. However, the solver doesn't care about grouping the data under these individual objects and it just operates on the whole system at once. Thus, it is efficient to have all the mesh data, in large Numpy arrays so all of the solver operations can be done wholesale.

Currently, I have a single class for the mesh but it's large and could be a lot cleaner. It would make sense to me that since the data for the mesh is specified object-wise, I could have a subclass that represents the individual objects. However, to avoid unnecessary copying, I would want the data to all still be stored in global Numpy arrays where each object just has a view of the chunk of the array that corresponds to it.

I'm unsure exactly how to structure the global mesh class and the subclass to properly handle this though. I have done some research but I haven't found anything that applies to this specific situation. The closest example that I have found to what I want to do would be shared-memory parallel processing, where each processor owns a chunk of some shared memory. However, in my situation, I want several objects of the same class to each own a chunk of the same Numpy array memory.

I should probably also mention that this is run in a real-time simulation type environment where multiple calls to the solver are made and parts of the mesh data may need to be updated between each call so I really don't want to be doing array copies to combine everything together.